# GoogleApiClient.blockingConnect() does not work with GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-api-client, google-signin, android-syncadapter

I have a `SyncAdapter` (code does not run on the UI thread) that writes to the app folder on Google Drive. This was working fine with the `GoogleApiClient` without Google Sign-In, but I am trying to move to  `GoogleApiClient` with Google Sign-In.

The working code without Google Sign-In:

```
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .setAccountName(accountName)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.blockingConnect();
```

Now that I have moved to using Google Sign-In it no longer works. The following code is what I am trying to use:

```
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.DRIVE_APPFOLDER))
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mApplication)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.blockingConnect();
```

My program falls over with the following error on the call to `blockingConnect()`:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot use SIGN_IN_MODE_REQUIRED with GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API. Use connect(SIGN_IN_MODE_OPTIONAL) instead.
```

Is there a way to perform a `blockingConnect()` with the Google Sign-In API?

Note that I perform an initial Sign-In on the UI thread before the `SyncAdapter` attempts the above code.

Comment: I forgot to add... I am using play-services 9.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the only way I can get the API to work from my `SyncAdapter` - the new API refuses to work with `blockingConnect()`:

```
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.DRIVE_APPFOLDER))
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mApplication)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect(GoogleApiClient.SIGN_IN_MODE_OPTIONAL);
    while (mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() && System.currentTimeMillis() - start < 5000) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(250, 0);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        try {
            // Do stuff with Google Drive.
        } finally {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }
```